# Collection view reusability

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, reusability

I do have 3 different controllers which have same List type of Cell i.e Product Display Cell,

I have created a custom tableview cell and done binding of all objects at cell level.

Now I need to show 3 Different types of list and grid cell, so I will have to transfer to transfer my code at Collection view.

but I do have cell level of configuration in tableview custom cell class, what if I want to use 3 different layout of same collection view cell,
As of Now I have to create 3 different cell and needs to write same code of cell configuration at 3 different places.

is there any way that I need to write Cell code once and then I can reuse it for different layouts.

Comment: Are the 3 different controllers viewControllers? Is the custom tableview cell a `NSTableCellView`? Do you want to use 3 different types of list and grid cell in each controller or has each controller only one type of list and grid cell? In which method do you customize the cell?

Comment: Are the 3 different controllers viewControllers?  YES
Is the custom tableview cell a NSTableCellView? No, UITableviewCell
Do you want to use 3 different types of list and grid cell in each controller or has each controller only one type of list and grid cell? 
It would be configurable, Either List Or Grid for all
In which method do you customize the cell?
From CellForRow: calling a method in customcellclass.
 probably will work in following way,
Will create a MasterCell, which will have all business logic.
Child Cell Will be inherited from maser cell and child will have own XIB Design.